# Column {name} is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, odbc

I have tried to look for the answer on here, but can't find it. I originally didn't have the SUM function in the code but fixed that and am still getting the error for SYNLIVE. The error is as follows: "Column 'X.dbo.POLIN.Description is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  Any help? I should also note that I am using the ODBC connection to pull the data into Microsoft Excel

```
SELECT 
   POLIN.Itemkey, POLIN.Description, POLIN.Location, 
   SUM(POLIN.Qtyremn), INLOC.Qtyonhand
FROM 
   X.dbo.INLOC INLOC, X.dbo.POLIN POLIN
WHERE 
   INLOC.Itemkey = POLIN.Itemkey 
   AND INLOC.Location = POLIN.Location 
   AND ((POLIN.Location = 'SPL') 
        AND (POLIN.Qtyremn > 0))
GROUP BY 
   POLIN.Itemkey, POLIN.Description
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are several columns in select clause that are not inside an aggregate function neither in group by clause:

```
SELECT polin.itemkey, 
       polin.description, 
       polin.location,             <-- this one
       Sum(polin.qtyremn), 
       inloc.qtyonhand             <-- this one
FROM   x.dbo.inloc INLOC, 
       x.dbo.polin POLIN 
WHERE  inloc.itemkey = polin.itemkey 
       AND inloc.location = polin.location 
       AND ( ( polin.location = 'SPL' ) 
             AND ( polin.qtyremn > 0 ) ) 
GROUP  BY polin.itemkey, 
          polin.description
```

A solution may be:

```
SELECT polin.itemkey, 
       polin.description, 
       polin.location,             
       inloc.qtyonhand ,
       Sum(polin.qtyremn)
FROM   x.dbo.inloc INLOC, 
       x.dbo.polin POLIN 
WHERE  inloc.itemkey = polin.itemkey 
       AND inloc.location = polin.location 
       AND ( ( polin.location = 'SPL' ) 
             AND ( polin.qtyremn > 0 ) ) 
GROUP  BY 
       polin.itemkey, 
       polin.description, 
       polin.location,             
       inloc.qtyonhand
```

Perhaps you are use to work with MySQL that allows [hidden columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: Is there any way to add a third table? I have tried, but am getting duplicate rows.

Comment: of course, but, for new question I suggest to you write new post.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the group by to:

```
GROUP BY POLIN.Itemkey, X.dbo.POLIN.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

Close... but here I think is what you're really after. Sum the QtyOnHand... do not group by it... otherwise you're probably OK. You are most likely getting duplicates of your first 3 fields... this should eliminate them. Also, use inner join instead of commas. New standard (as mentioned above ... since like 88... yes... 1988.)

```
SELECT polin.itemkey, 
       polin.description, 
       polin.location,             
       Sum(inloc.qtyonhand) [qtyonhand] ,
       Sum(polin.qtyremn)[qtyremn]
FROM   x.dbo.inloc INLOC
INNER JOIN x.dbo.polin POLIN on inloc.itemkey = polin.itemkey 
       AND inloc.location = polin.location 
WHERE ( ( polin.location = 'SPL' ) 
             AND ( polin.qtyremn > 0 ) ) 
GROUP  BY 
       polin.itemkey, 
       polin.description, 
       polin.location
```